# How to troubleshoot Firestore Total timeout?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I have several Cloud Functions running with Google Cloud that interact with Firebase.

All but one of the functions are working normally, reading and writing to Firebase. The one function gets an error:

> Total timeout of API google.firestore.v1.Firestore exceeded 60000
> milliseconds before any response...

I checked the section for errors and logs. There's no indication of a problem, or nothing descriptive at least. The first time I saw this error several days ago, I resolved by linking a billing account, just based on a guess. How can I troubleshoot this issue now?

[image]?

Comment: If the problem was resolved by linking a billing account and now the problem has returned, my guess is that you have a payment problem. Go to your payments account and check for a payment issue.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, but no billing issue exists. The first issue was just going from free to paid. Right now, 7/8 of the cloud functions read/write to firestore successfully, but the 8th function was stuck for ~4 hours and is now working again (with no billing changes this time)

Comment: From above conversation, I believe your issue is resolved. If yes, can you post your solution as answer? So that it helps others too.

Comment: @RoopaM I did not solve the problem, it resolved on its own. The question is about how to debug such occurrences, so I will still wait for advice.

Comment: I hope your question is answered [here](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/How-to-troubleshoot-Firestore-quot-Total-timeout-quot-from/m-p/598447) and also have a look at [this document](https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/firestore-datastore-requests-terminated-within-60-seconds-despite-timeout-value-configured-to-be-greater-than-60-seconds-000004805)